# "Filling" the "RegionIntersection"

Tags: plotting

How can I use "Filling" to fill the area that is derived from "RegionIntersection"?
For example,

```
RegionPlot[{f1(β,ϕ), f2(β,ϕ), f3(β,ϕ)}, FrameLabel -> {β, ϕ}, 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Black], PlotStyle -> Directive[White], 
 BoundaryStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[c/255]]]
```

How can I use "Filling" to fill the area f3?

Answer (score 5):

[`Filling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) is not an option for [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
Options[RegionPlot, Filling]
```

[image]

Use [`PlotStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotStyle.html)

```
r1 = Disk[{0, 0}, 2];

r2 = Disk[{0, 3}, 2];

r12 = RegionIntersection[r1, r2];

RegionPlot[{r1, r2, r12}, 
 PlotStyle -> {White, White, LightBlue},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
 AspectRatio -> 7/4]
```

[image]